# Reinstall Joomla Site with existing MySQL database

Tags: php, content-management-system, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

My client joomla website is 1.7 version.Now their web site does not show anything on both frond end and backend also coz they make wrong configuration.I can reinstall this joomla website with existing database?Reinstalling website can fix this issue.please don't vote down my question coz I'm beginner only in joomla CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry are you looking to save the database so that you can reinstall joomla without having to re do all the databases?